# Laravel - SimpleXMLElement' not found

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, php-7

I read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397036/how-to-convert-array-to-simplexmls) and another examples. I want to convert array to XML using Laravel (and php7) . 
Here is my code :

```
   public function siteMap() 
    {
        if (function_exists('simplexml_load_file')) {
            echo "simpleXML functions are available.<br />\n";
        } else {
            echo "simpleXML functions are not available.<br />\n";
        }
        $array = array (
            'bla' => 'blub',
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'another_array' => array (
                'stack' => 'overflow',
            ),
        );
        $xml = simplexml_load_string('<root/>');

        array_walk_recursive($array, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
        print $xml->asXML();
    }
```

It's my first try . it returns me :

```
simpleXML functions are available.
blafoostack
```

My second try is :

```
public function siteMap() 
{

    $test_array = array (
        'bla' => 'blub',
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'another_array' => array (
            'stack' => 'overflow',
        ),
    );
    $this->array_to_xml($test_array);

}
private function array_to_xml(array $arr, SimpleXMLElement $xml = NULL)
{
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        is_array($v)
            ? array_to_xml($v, $xml->addChild($k))
            : $xml->addChild($k, $v);
    }
    return $xml;
}
```

I had an error in this situation :

**Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on null**

Here what I want :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <blub>bla</blub>
  <bar>foo</bar>
  <overflow>stack</overflow>
</root>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: add `echo <pre>;` before `print $xml->asXML();` in the 1st code to see your xml

Comment: @splash58 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: echo "<pre>"; - https://eval.in/603925

Comment: @splash58 it doesn't log anything https://eval.in/603937

Comment: haven't you seen xml you want ?

Comment: @splash58 Yes, I saw result on that page, but I'm using php7 and my output is : blafoostack

Answer (score -1):

Notice that you have a `SimpleXMLElement $xml = null` in your method signature:

```
private function array_to_xml(array $arr, SimpleXMLElement $xml = NULL)
```

Now, notice that you call this method like this:

```
$this->array_to_xml($test_array); // <--- No second parameter
```

This means that the variable `$xml` is `null` in the `array_to_xml()` context because you didn't give the method and 2nd parameter (so it defaults to `NULL`). Since you never built an actual element, it gives you

> Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on null

You either have to give the method the necessary element

```
$this->array_to_xml($test_array, new SimpleXMLElement);
```

or build the element inside the method

```
private function array_to_xml(array $arr)
{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement();
    ...
}
```